# is it possible to Delay Linux OOM Killer and run my process?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, real-time

**Am currently trying to create an efficient dynamic memory allocation for virtual machines in virtualized environment using QEMU/KVM.**

**My final problem** is when the guest virtual machine almost run out of memory it will use OOM Killer and prevent anything working without enough memory. but what am doing is that when the machine is almost running out of memory my algorithm will take some free memory from other guest virtual machine and allocate it to that the machine that need it.

so i have disable **swap**, **ksm** is not running and final thing is that **OOM killer** is killing other programs.

i have read and search for disabling OOM killer and i found its bad idea to disable it.

**So now asking here is there a way i can delay the OOM Killer for 1 or 2 second and let the process running because my algorithm will allocate memory for the machine already.**

or can the process running and allocate memory even if there is no memory so my algorithm will allocate memory for that machine.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

The possible values of oom_adj range from -17 to +15. The higher the score, more likely the associated process is to be killed by OOM-killer. If oom_adj is set to -17, the process is not considered for OOM-killing.

for more reference [link 1](https://lwn.net/Articles/317814/), [link 2](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer)

Answer (score 0):

echo -1000 > /proc/yourPID/oom_score_adj
this will make oom killer skip your process.